# VBA to copy fields from external application to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to use a VBA in excel to copy rows/columns of data from my organisation's trading platform (Fidessa) to an excel workbook. The problem I've encountered however is that Fidessa doesn't have an excel plug-in as standard. So is there a way for excel or VBA to automatically copy and paste fields of data from external applications such as Fidessa?

I'm relatively new to VBA so any help would be welcome, thanks!

Used VBA code to copy data as screenshot but this is not suitable. It needs to be the data rows/columns from Fidessa copied across to Excel in order for it to be viable/functional.

Comment: This is not possible if your application doesn't support VBA. Can you export the data? Is it accessible through a browser? If not, there is not much you can do

Comment: I disagree with above. It depends on how you manually complete the process. If you use copy past method you can use a `Shell()` command using those keys for that specific window. This is saying this COULD be possible, but no guarentees.

Comment: Hi Dean, do you have any suggestions on where I could begin with this method? Thanks!

Comment: @NHure92 You should provide more info on the application. Is it a web platform (which you could possibly scrape)? Does it provide any options to export data in some format?

Comment: @StavrosJon - It is a proprietary trading platform/exchange, unfortunately there is no possibility to scrape the data..the only possibility for now is to manually copy and paste the data which is what I would like to change if possible